# Django model validation does not occur in the shell

Tags: django, django-models

I have an ostensibly simple problem. Here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Email(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.email
    email = models.EmailField()
```

EmailField, [according to the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#emailfield), should check if the entered email address is valid. So then why does my shell allow me to save malformed emails? In the shell:

```
>>> from emailapp.models import Email
>>> e = Email(email="sdf")
>>> e
<Email: sdf>
>>> e.save()
>>> Email.objects.all()
[<Email: sdf@sdf.com>, <Email: sadcljhn@aef.ce>, <Email: sdf>]
```

The admin interface doesn't allow me to save these malformed emails, but the shell does.Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation is explicit that [you have to call validation yourself](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects).

Comment: Where would I call this validation? I am still not clear where to place the validating code so that I won't be able to save() on the console without this validation taking place. Will I have to overwrite the save() function as julio says below? Is [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) the only way I can do it?

Answer (score 2):

Some field validators are enabled only in forms (django admin use a form). In this case, the `EmailField` is just translated to a `CharField` (into the database), and that's why you are not getting any errors from shell.

I think this is made because is not very common to create models from the shell. If you still want to validate correct emails from anywhere they are created I recommend you to overwrite the `save()` method:

```
from django.core.validators import email_re
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not email_re.match(self.email):
        raise  ValidationError(u'%s is not a correct email' % self.email)
    super(Email, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

Other than overwriting the save() method, another way of performing model validations, would be to use Django's [pre_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save). You can create a pre_save signal hook. The hook can call the full_clean() method, which will perform the model validations.